# SharePoint Online - Show/display column in default view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I am adding a site column into a document library default view and want it to be visible/shown when you click onto the list itself. However, I am unsure on how to do this. The code I have so far

```
// Get the view (this is the default view)  
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.View v = Employeecvlist.GetViewByName("All Documents");

// Load it up
clientContext.Load(v, x => x.ViewFields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

// Get the field I want to add to the view
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field name = 
Employeecvlist.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Name");

clientContext.Load(name);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

// Add this field to the view !! Nothing else in the view object to allow to make it visible by default !!
v.ViewFields.Add(name.InternalName);

// Finally, update the view
v.Update();
```

If you look at the image file below, I basically want to be able to check the "display" checkbox to true for the above field.

[image: Edit view Screen - display columns]

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` again to persist the changes. Also, there's no need to do it twice to load your objects, load everything you need and then get it from the server:

```
//Put following line in the using section
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

//Your code
View v = Employeecvlist.GetViewByName("All Documents");
Field name = Employeecvlist.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Name");

clientContext.Load(v, x => x.ViewFields);
clientContext.Load(name);

v.ViewFields.Add(name.InternalName);
v.Update();

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```